# Should I set short or long URL fragments for headlines?

Tags: seo, url, anchor

I have an article like:

```html
<h1>My article example</h1>
<div class="table-of-content">
    <a href="#subheadline-example-here">Subheadline example here...</a>
    <a href="#another-title-example-text">Another example title text</a>
</div>
<h2 id="subheadline-example-here">Subheadline example here...</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
<h2 id="another-example-title-text">Another example title text</h2>
<p>Text...</p>
```

So, there is a table of content and sometimes I see from Google Analytics that users come (click) exactly to `<h2>` headline from Google search.

The question is should I make `identifier` like I do with slug or should I make it like WordPress `#i1`, `#i2`, I mean short? Why I ask: because I know search engines like short URLs and maybe short URLs rank much better. But having slug identifier make it very long:

- `http://example.com/seaction-name/how-to-make-laugh.html#benefits-of-making-people-laugh-and-fun`
- `http://example.com/seaction-name/how-to-make-laugh.html#i1`

Which option is better?